# Iterate over list of urls and replace space with %20

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a client that gave me a list of urls that I need to check but the list contains urls with white spaces - ex: "https://exdomain.com/dir/this is just%20a%20text.html"

I need to iterate over this list and replace all the spaces for %20.
I know that is a best practice to use - instead of %20 but that's a problem to solve in the future.

What I've done so far is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['urls_with_spaces', 'urls_with_%20'])

df['urls_with_spaces'] = 
['https://exdomain.com/dir/this is just%20a%20text.jpg', 
'https://exdomain.com/dir/this is just%20a%20text2.jpg', 
'https://subdomain.exdomain.com/dir/this is just%20a%20text3.jpg']

df['urls_with_%20'] = [x.replace(' ', '%20') for x in data['urls_with_%20']]
```

Now, the problem is that there are urls that have line breaks, so I can replace the spaces for %20 but because of this line breaks I cannot access the urls after doing this.

An example of what I'm getting:

```
"https://subdomain.exdomain.com/content/x/ex/region/subregion/something/this
Is%20an%20example/x2/w-program/get-out.jpg
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `df['urls_with_%20'] = df['urls_with_spaces'].str.replace('\s','%20')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to match all whitespaces, not only the space with `\s`:

```
import re
...
df['urls_with_%20'] = [re.sub(r'\s+', '%20', x) for x in data['urls_with_spaces']]
```

Alternatively, you can try using [`urlib.parse.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote), but I'm not sure how it will handle break lines in your case:

```
from urlib.parse import quote
...
df['urls_with_%20'] = [quote(x) for x in data['urls_with_spaces']]
```